# Application can't find python library installed as rpm

Tags: python, centos, virtualenv, rpm

I have a python application that's run inside a virtualenv on CentOS. This application needs a python library that's distributed and installed as an rpm. When the application runs I just get

`no module named ...`.

I've verified that the rpm is installed correctly, and I've also installed the rpm in the site-packages directory of the virtualenv but that didn't help. What is the correct way to install an rpm so that an application running in a virtual environment has access to it?

Comment: I forget the actual rpm command but can you make a list of the files included by your install? If it's inside site-packages, you might need to enable that when you create the virtualenv. Is there a version mismatch between you system python and virtualenv python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default virtual environments don't access modules in site-packages. You either need to allow such access (`toggleglobalsitepackages` in virtualenvwrapper) or recreate you virtualenv allowing such access with option `--system-site-packages`.

Comment: This worked! Also (as I should've thought of) it works to add the path of the installed rpm to PYTHON_PATH

Answer (score 0):

It also might be a dependency problem. Try to reinstall the RPM using `yum` instead of `rpm`:

```
yum -y reinstall /path/to/your/file.rpm
```